# Replacing webhelpers with paginate: how to port PageURL_WebOb? (py2 to py3)

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, pyramid

## Porting Python 2 to Python 3

As you can read [here](https://webhelpers2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/migrate.html#webhelpers-paginate) the Python 2 package `webhelpers.paginate` no longer exists under Python 3.
Instead they created an extra module `paginate` for Python 3 (which can be found [here](https://pypi.org/project/paginate/)).

#### Python 2

When working with `pyramid` under Python 2, the code looks like this:

```
# request is a pyramid request
def get_paginator(request, page=1, items_per_page=10):
    page_url = PageURL_WebOb(request)
    return Page(sql-query-here, page, url=page_url, items_per_page=items_per_page)
```

#### Python 3

Under Python 3 they removed the `PageURL_WebOb` from `paginate`.
So is it somehow possible to retrieve the `page_url` directly from the `request`?

How would a correct port to Python 3 look like?

Comment: Does [this issue](https://github.com/Pylons/paginate/issues/2) help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So with the help of *Steve Piercy* and [this issue](https://github.com/Pylons/paginate/issues/2) from the official `paginate` git I was able to port it in the following way:

```
# request is a pyramid request
def get_paginator(request, page=1, items_per_page=10):
    def url_maker(page_number):
        query = request.GET
        query["page"] = str(page_number)
        return request.current_route_url(_query=query)

    return Page(sql-query-here, page=page, items_per_page=items_per_page, url_maker=url_maker)
```